# Is it possible to confirm prompt alert with variable?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to do e2e test using protractor and I need to accept prompt alert ( type my API key ) for login to system.

How to type text(variable) in input and click OK in alert box using protractor? Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of alert box is it - could you post it's HTML representation? Thanks.

Comment: function login() {
        setCookie('my_api_key', window.prompt('API Key:'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the alert, send keys to it and then accept:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000);
var alert = browser.switchTo().alert();

alert.sendKeys("api key");
alert.accept();
```